# UTC time with 7 decimals calculation

Tags: php, unix, utc, epoch, seconds

I need to calculate the difference between 2 UTC time values with 7 decimals in PHP 7.3

Can I simply do the following:

```
val1 = 20200205120415.6513380; //first timestamp
val2 = 20200205120415.6535670; //second timestamp
$diff = $val2 - $val1; //should be difference between the 2 timestamps
```

The value of the above calculation is 0.002229. If I am doing it correctly is that value in seconds or microseconds and will I be able to convert it into a UNIX epoch timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that the above times are not simple numbers; they BCD (binary coded decimal) for 2020-02-05-12:04:15.6513380. You can't do simple math on these, and you'll need to parse them to convert to a unix timestamp.

Depending on your language, it may be easiest to parse these by turning them into strings and taking the first four characters as the year, the next two as the month, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution for completeness.

The values on the right of the . is indeed fractional seconds. So in PHP to get the difference I did the following:

```
$start = 20200205120415.6513380;
$end = 20200205120415.6535670;

//get value left of . and then create datetime object to later convert to seconds
list($datetime, $usecStart) = explode(".", $start);
$startTime = date_create_from_format("YmdHis", $datetime);
list($datetime, $usecEnd) = explode(".", $end);
$endTime = date_create_from_format("YmdHis", $datetime);

//get timestamp in seconds and add franction or microseconds back
$start = $startTime->getTimestamp().".".$usecStart;
$end = $endTime->getTimestamp().".".$usecEnd;

//get difference in seconds and fraction or microseconds
echo $end - $start;
```

Here is another way using datetime->diff() function:

```
$start = new DateTime('2020-02-05T12:04:15.6513380Z');
$end = new DateTime('2020-02-05T12:04:15.6535670Z');

$diff = $start->diff($end);
echo $diff->format('%h:%i:%s.%F');
```